# Cannot read property 'type' of null An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'type' of null

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-aot

So we are using angular 9 , we are  applying scope to all our library project in our organization.
So in order to do so , I updated my existing library pacakge.json project name with @myorgname/lib_name. And changed imports everywhere i was using from previous to new one.
But while building the project I am getting this error.

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null
    at /home/advitiya.srivastava/Documents/data-transform-mapping-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13783:31
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at removeSummaryDuplicates (/home/advitiya.srivastava/Documents/data-transform-mapping-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13782:15)
    at TemplateParser.tryParseHtml (/home/advitiya.srivastava/Documents/data-transform-mapping-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13174:38)
    at TemplateParser.tryParse (/home/advitiya.srivastava/Documents/data-transform-mapping-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13167:25)
    at TemplateParser.parse (/home/advitiya.srivastava/Documents/data-transform-mapping-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13145:31)
    at AotCompiler._parseTemplate (/home/advitiya.srivastava/Documents/data-transform-mapping-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27252:47)
    at AotCompiler._createTypeCheckBlock (/home/advitiya.srivastava/Documents/data-transform-mapping-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:26997:27)
    at /home/advitiya.srivastava/Documents/data-transform-mapping-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:26966:31
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```